# What are the chances of encountering a enemy every time you move?

Tags: fnaf-world

So every time you move in FNAF World there's a chance to encounter an enemy like gear rat, but what exactly are those chances? Is it static for the whole game or do certain areas have a better chance of starting a battle? I tried looking for these answers but the only ones I could find were about character encounters instead of enemy ones.